# How to update an existing record in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP and following its tutorial. I want to update a record but when i do its create another record not updating. according to tutorial my code is given below

```
$data = array('Id' => $id, 'Approved' => 12);
$this->names->save($data);
```

it results in

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   `4` for key `PRIMARY`

And if I do this

```
$this->names->Id=$id;
```

It adds a new record. How should I fix this ?

Comment: I think you are not following cake conventions. Model name should be start with capital letter

Comment: Moyed Ansari - that's irrelevant to the question he asked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$this->names->id=$id;                
$this->names->set(array('Approved'=>12));                
$this->names->save();
```

Comment: Follow above code snippet, It **creat new record, not update** yet.

Comment: @DoNhuVy Notice that $id must be equal to your id in your db. This is the key to making save update, instead of insert. You HAVE to set the model primary key to the already existing primary key.

Answer (score 4):

The key must be `id` and not `Id`. If in your table you can't use id (lowercase) and you have to use Id (uppercase) then you have to set it in your Model file

also you are not followeing the conventions: the model should be Name and not names (singular and CamelCase)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're intentionally not following Cake naming conventions (with a strong reason), you should stick to it. That means, models should be capitalized-singular named, and table fields should be lowercase. Also, your data array has to have the name of the model you want to save.

So:

```
$data = array('Name' => array('id' => $id, 'approved' => 12));
$this->Name->save($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

To update a single field value when you have the primary key available, [`saveField()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false) is also available.

Quoting from [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false):

> ```
> Model::saveField(string $fieldName, string $fieldValue, $validate = false)
> ```
>
> Used to save a single field value. Set the ID of the model
>   (`$this->ModelName->id = $id`) just before calling `saveField()`. When
>   using this method, `$fieldName` should only contain the name of the
>   field, not the name of the model and field.
>   For example, to update the title of a blog post, the call to saveField
>   from a controller might look something like this:
>
> ```
> $this->Post->saveField('title', 'A New Title for a New Day');
> ```

It also has facility for passing parameters like `validate`, `callbacks` etc using an alternate syntax:

> ```
> saveField(string $fieldName, string $fieldValue, array $params = array())
> ```

References: [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false), [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-Model.html#_saveField)